# Connection reset while sending data from AWS Lambda to SQS queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm using AWS SDK for Java in which I'm sending data from AWS Lambda to SQS.

We are getting exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:886)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:857)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:160)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:120)
at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.writeTo(StringEntity.java:167)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:63)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1236)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
```

Code:

```
 List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> sqsList= new LinkedList<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry>();
    int batchId = 0; //To send a unique batchId for each msg in a batch
    for (Metadata metadata: metadataList) {
        String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(metadata);
        sqsList.add(new SendMessageBatchRequestEntry(batchId + "", jsonString));
        batchId++;
    }
    amazonSqs.sendMessageBatch(new SendMessageBatchRequest(queueUrl, sqsList));
```

Background what we are trying to do:

*We have a main Lambda function which create and initialize an SQS queue, and contain detail for every record that should be processed.
Now SQS queue need to set up for creating batches of X number of messages from the queue and automatically invoke another SQS Lambda function for each of the batches.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of messages per batch is 10. You cannot fill the SQS queue with 20k at once and send that request. Try to break it into 10's.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html#limits-queues

Comment: Thanks Dejan. A simple tweak in code has worked. Adding code in the answer of this question.

Answer (score 2):

We can send it in the batch size of 10.
Working code:

```
List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> sqsList= new LinkedList<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry>();
    int batchId = 1; //To send a unique batchId for each msg in a batch
    for (Metadata metadata: metadataList) {
        String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(metadata);
        if (sqsList.size() == 10) {
            amazonSqs.sendMessageBatch(new SendMessageBatchRequest(queueUrl, sqsList));
            sqsList.clear();
        } 
        sqsList.add(new SendMessageBatchRequestEntry(batchId + "", jsonString)); 
        batchId++;
    }
    if(sqsList.size()>0) {
        amazonSqs.sendMessageBatch(new SendMessageBatchRequest(queueUrl, sqsList));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is fine, and as far as I remember (I have seen this error myself several times), this happens from time to time when using SDK due to how SDK reuses HTTP connections. This error only tells you that your the Lambda, well, reseted the HTTP connection, but SDK has build in functionality to retry failed requests so you should be fine if you don't see this error on every single request.

Comment: Thanks Matus... Even i don't mind if the SDK has failover for this. But it happen for me every time. Total number of record which are trying to send is around 20k. Is the number of data which is creating a problem ?

Comment: @Raushan Are you using FIFO or standard queue, and what is the size of a message that you are sending into the queue?

Comment: It's a standard queue. And the size is 6800 KB :(. How to breakdown this ? I mean it should send in batches to the queue so that the other Lambda process it in batch. ( As we are restricted to 15 mins).

Comment: @Raushan Max size of a message that you can send to queue is 256 KB, anything larger will be dropped. There are some workarounds for this but I would need to know the use case and contents of the messages. Why is the message so large?

Comment: Well...We are moving our CRON jobs from EC2 instance to Lambda. One of the job which has 20k records and for each record need to collect their metadata from the service. So 15 mins is going to be short. Then we thought to push these data to queue and later handle this from another lambda which process X records in a single invocation. So SQS queue need to be created in batches of X message. That's why we are doing this. Hope I am going in right direction !!!

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the best use case for Lambda. But here is one thing that you can do even without using SQS. Use one Lambda function that will receive the the whole job. Use it only to split the job into reasonable chunks (something which single function can process) and fan-out these smaller tasks into multiple Lambdas. You can then send those partial results into S3 and recombine them. Note that this is not suitable for every scenario and you need to evaluate whether it is appropriate for you or not.

Comment: What about trying with step functions?